# DatePicker with the ability to choose a span

Tags: wpf, datepicker

Here is a quick visual of the idea that I got from Google Analytics.

ComboBox Collapsed:

[ComboBox Collapsed http://www.googlemapscontrol.net/images/CalendarDropDownClosed.jpg](http://www.googlemapscontrol.net/images/CalendarDropDownClosed.jpg)

ComboBox Expanded:

[ComboBox Expanded http://www.googlemapscontrol.net/images/CalendarDropDownOpen.jpg](http://www.googlemapscontrol.net/images/CalendarDropDownOpen.jpg)

I am not concerned with the functionality of the timeline or the date range text boxes. Basically I am looking to have something that looks kind of like a ComboBox with a single calendar control. When the date range is selected and the control is closed then the range is shown in the text box.

I don't think that I can get a ComboBox to behave this way and I think that I need to use something along the lines of a textblock, button and a popup.

Does anyone have a sample I can start with?

If you don't have a sample how would you approach this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WPF Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf) has a Calendar/DatePicker control that could be a suitable base for you to modify into an elaborate date range picker.

I would start with the DatePicker Generic.xaml file from the WPF Toolkit distribution, and examine what they have done with the DatePicker control template. The interesting section for you will be around the area that `PART_TextBox` and `PART_Button` is used. They indeed use a combination of grids, textbox, button, and popup controls.

Hope that helps!